# reading csv and create row -1 as value in new column

Tags: r, csv

i have set of csv files which consists same format of data across all the files.
The format is as below

```
CA.csv  -- 

row:1- jones            
row:2- May          
row:3-
row:4- Date_transaction cards_hold  status  amount
row:5- 5/25/2018 3:15      2            Active  233
row:6- 5/25/2018 3:30      2            Active  4534

 NY.csv  --
row:1- gary         
row:2- May          
row:3-
row:4- Date_transaction cards_hold  status  amount
row:5- 5/25/2018 5:00      2            Active  565
row:6- 5/25/2018 6:30      2            Active  533
```

The above format repeats for all other csv files

```
o/p (i.e name is in first row in csv file should read and create as value in "name" column)
Date_transaction    cards_hold  status  amount  name
5/25/2018 3:15     2            Active  233     jones
5/25/2018 3:30     2            Active  4534    jones
5/25/2018 5:00     2            Active  565     gary
5/25/2018 6:30     2            Active  533     gary
```

I have tried with below code.

```
 files <- dir("RawData", recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE, pattern="\\.csv$")
   raw = rbindlist(lapply(files, fread))
```

Comment: Can you describe your problem a bit more ? And btw the csv in your second codebox has a column named "name and the other not. I thought you were telling us they are the same ?

Comment: second codebox is desired o/p which append all rows from row-6 in all csv files and creating new column "name" by row-1 from all csv files with row-4 as column names .the format is same for all csv files

Comment: How do your files actually look like? Is the filename part of the file? Is this `row:x-` part of the file? Does each file have only two records, or how many? What is the field separator - you call it a CSV, but I see spaces, or are they tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
setwd("directory_path_of_your_csv_files/")
file_lst <- list.files(".")

read_all_csv <- function(f_name){
  csv_data <- read.csv(f_name, header=T, stringsAsFactors=F, skip=3)
  name <- read.csv(f_name, header=F, nrows=1)$V1
  csv_data$name <- rep(name, nrow(csv_data))
  csv_data
}

df <- Reduce(rbind, lapply(file_lst, function(x) read_all_csv(x)))
```

Comment: Thanks @prem , i have used df <- Reduce(rbind, lapply(file_lst, function(x) read_all_csv(x))) instead of reduce since it throws an error "Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names"